# For each cell in a range, if a value in a seperate range is found in the next cell do stuff

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

This Macro I have built works but I am hoping for a faster version or a Formula that will do the same in less time.

What I Have:

```
    For Each cell In Range("Table_Query_1[[#Data],[Reason2]]")
        For Each PossibleValue In Range("F2", Range("F2").End(xlDown))
            If Len(cell) = 0 Then
             If (InStr(UCase(cell.Offset(0, 1)), UCase(PossibleValue)) <> 0) Then
               cell.Value = PossibleValue.Value
             End If
             Else
                Exit For
             End If
         Next
         If Len(cell) = 0 Then
            cell.Value = cell.Offset(0, -1)
        End If
    Next
```

The only other way I could get anything to work way with the following Array Formula

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH($F$3:$F$10,[@Extra Info],0)),[@Reason],$F$3:$F$10)
```

but this doesn't work for Partial matches as in the case of Row 4 and 9. I also have my doubts that this array formula would be that much faster then a vba macro along with the fact it would also require more upkeep with the test values range (F2:f3) in this case as I would have to constantly update that formula OR I wouild have to make the original range like F2:F100 witch would cause it to take that much longer.

[image: Sample]

So, what i'd like is if ANY value in my range of values (F2:F3 in this case), Is found inside of the Extra Info Column on the current Row , Then Reason2 of that row (Offset(0, -1)) equals the Value that was matched. But if nothing is found then just use the Reason in that row(Offset(0,1)).

And the second Issue is that I need the Macro to Run After the QueryTable refreshes but if I set it as a Cell Change Event on a cell the is in the query that will change, the macro runs and finishes before the Final querytable is imported and sorted.

Comment: I have found a formula for partial match but I am stuck in retrieving which number from `possible values` is in in `Extra Info`

Comment: Could you share your patrial match formula? maybe it could help lead my direction?

Comment: This will go in Cell `B2` It is an array formula. `=IF(COUNT(FIND($F$2:$F$3,C1)),"What Will Go Here",A1)`

Comment: It is an array formula. Instead of pressing enter. You have to press control + shift + enter

Comment: @SiddharthRout So that leave us with something like `=IF(AND($F$2<>0,COUNT(FIND($F$2,C2))),$F$2,IF(AND($F$3<>0,COUNT(FIND($F$3,C2))),$F$3,IF(AND($F$4<>0,COUNT(FIND($F$4,C2))),$F$4,A2)))` Now would that be faster then my Macro though? *NOTE:* The actual `F` column will be more like 10-20 values long.

Comment: That formula give me an error.

Comment: Not sure why as it is working for me, but I really do not like it.

Comment: Anyways i made a change and it works now but then you are hardcoing each cells from F so if the list is 1000 cells long in F then it will be a problem.

Comment: Exactly my I wrote my own Macro. But is that formula going to be fasteR?

Comment: I am still playing with it.. let's see if i can find a way to come up with "What Will Go Here"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

This is post the comment that I posted above which had the initial formula.

`=IF(COUNT(FIND($F$2:$F$3,C1)),"What Will Go Here",A1)`

The below tells you what has to go in place of `"What Will Go Here"`

Put this formula in cell B2. Note that this is an Array Formula. You will have to press  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> after you enter the formula.

`=IF(COUNT(FIND($F$2:$F$4,C2)),INDEX($F$2:$F$4,MATCH(SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(--FIND($F$2:$F$4,C2,1)),--FIND($F$2:$F$4,C2,1))),FIND($F$2:$F$4,C2,1),0),0),A2)`

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Explanation**:

`FIND($F$2:$F$4,C2,1)` when used with an array returns an array. To check the values you can highlight it and press <kbd>F9</kbd> and it will tell you the position at which the match is found. See this screenshot

[image]

So it tells us that it found the match at the 3rd position in 4532. It yet doesn't tell us with what did it find a match.

Now the next step is to retrieve the position of that number from the array. So in the above example it will be position 2 and to find that position we will use `MATCH()` and to use MATCH we will need that `3`

So to retrieve `3` from the array we use this formula

`=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(--FIND($F$2:$F$4,C2,1)),--FIND($F$2:$F$4,C2,1)))`

[image]

Now we have that `3` so we will use it in `Match` to find the position in the `Possible Value`

`=MATCH(SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(--FIND($F$2:$F$4,C2,1)),--FIND($F$2:$F$4,C2,1))),FIND($F$2:$F$4,C2,1),0)`

This will give us `2`

[image]

Now we know the position of the number in the `Possible Value`. To find that number we will use `INDEX`

`=INDEX($F$2:$F$4,MATCH(SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(--FIND($F$2:$F$4,C2,1)),--FIND($F$2:$F$4,C2,1))),FIND($F$2:$F$4,C2,1),0),0)`

[image]

**SAMPLE Workbook**

http://wikisend.com/download/280280/Sample.xlsx

Comment: I got #N/A on all matches and 0 on all non matches. Copy pasted your exact formula and entered as Array (Verified by the surrounding {} in formula)

Comment: Also do you really think that using this will be Faster then the Macro in my original post? It seems like its going to go through much more work.

Comment: I just tested it and it works. Here is a sample. http://wikisend.com/download/280280/Sample.xlsx I believe it should be faster than VBA but I have not tested it. Also I have added the explanation to the above post so that you will have no problem understanding it. You might have to refresh the page to see it.

Comment: So, I finally got around to playing with this. The only problem is that it FIND is Case-Sensitive. To fix this I Replaced the `FIND` with `SEARCH`.

Comment: This is being used for Text, the numbers were just for sample data. the actual values are Given Reason, Master Reason and Description of Reason. The given reason is populated with a drop down and the description is a text box for additional info, and we would like to have a master list of possible Descriptions that will override the given reason is a master reason is in the description, but if a master description value does not exist in the description to use the Main reason. Basically just looking for key words for data consolidation.

Comment: Yes, other then that can i ask why you included the `--` before the find in the code as I removed those and it still seems to work fine.

Comment: I have added another answer you might be interested in for future use.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution I came across that does not have to be Array Entered and seems to run faster then Siddharth Rout's solution. I am using the formula

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(1E+100,SEARCH($F$2:$F$4,C2),$F$2:$F$4),A2)
```

Where I am looking for any word in C2 that is in the range F2:F4. If none found it will throw an `ERROR` and in that situation I know nothing was found and simply return the original reason.

Not shown in the picture I also turn F2:F4 into a named range called `Reasons` and change the formula too:

```
    =IFERROR(LOOKUP(1E+100,SEARCH(Reasons,C2),Reasons),A2)
```

[image]