# Match text from column within a certain cell - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of few thousand filenames that are not uniform. For instance:

```
|     Column A     | Column B |
===============================
| junk_City1_abunc | City1    |
-------------------------------
| nunk_City1_blahb | City1    |
-------------------------------
| small=City2_jdjf | City2    |
-------------------------------
| mozrmcity3_somet | City3    |
```

I would like to identify the city within the text in column A and return it in Column B.

I've come up with a complex formula that does the trick, but it is difficult to adjust if more cities are added within the filenames in new entries within column A.

Here is an example:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH("*"&$W$3&"*",I248,0)),IF(ISNA(MATCH("*"&$W$4&"*",I248,0)),IF(ISNA(MATCH("*"&$W$5&"*",I248,0)),IF(ISNA(MATCH("*"&$W$6&"*",I248,0)),IF(ISNA(MATCH("*"&$W$7&"*",I248,0)),IF(ISNA(MATCH("*"&$W$8&"*",I248,0)),"Austin","Orlando"),"Las Vegas"),"Chicago"),"Boston"),"Las Angeles"),"National")
```

It seems like there should be an easier way to do it, but I just can't figure it out.

(To make matters worse, not only am I identifying a city within the filename, I'm looking for other attributes to populate other columns)

Can anyone help?

Comment: There are two different approaches. The first would be to identify the seperators like "_" and "=" if they follow an order and get the string (city) inbetween. The second would be another column having all existing cities and check if one exists in Column A

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to check each cell (in column A) to see if it contains one of the values in your list of cities, if it does you want this value in Column B?

Comment: `Las Angeles` -> `Los Angeles`

Comment: Possible duplicate of my question [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16066123)

Comment: @SvenRojek Even in this small list of 4 (and the question states there's thousands)  you would already have trouble just with `mozrmcity3_somet` as it isn't fully seperated but only post seperated. and we have no idea how the rest looks. Based on this sample we'd be better off with parsing numerics + the left 4 characters, but this would have many holes.

Comment: Wow, that was quick. Thank you so much everyone... To answer the questions above, the separators aren't necessarily uniform throughout, which sucks. As for the columns... I want to check if one of a list of cities is within column A, then have the specific name of the city returned in column B (It is a little misleading as it is laid out above)...I'll check out the solutions you all have suggested now. Again, thank you for pitching in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the formula `=IFERROR(LOOKUP(1E+100,SEARCH($E$2:$E$11,A2),$E$2:$E$11),A2)`

This does *****NOT***** have to be array entered.

Where $E$2:$E$11 is the list of names you want returned and A2 is the cell to test

If no matches are found instead of errors you will just use the full name in column b.

If you want errors or expect to NEVER have then you can just use:

```
=LOOKUP(1E+100,SEARCH($E$2:$E$11,A2),$E$2:$E$11)
```

[image]

Comment: THIS WORKED! I have spent countless hours on this. I cannot thank you enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a round about way that works, not all my own work but a mish mash of bits from other sources:

Assuming the sheet is setup as follows:

[image: Starting Position]

The formula to use is below, this **must be entered using** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$8,MAX(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH($C$2:$C$8,A2)),-1,1)*(ROW($C$2:$C$8)-ROW($C$2)+1)))
```

Annotated version:

```
=INDEX([List of search terms],MAX(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH([List of search terms],[Cell to search])),-1,1)*(ROW([List of search terms])-ROW([Cell containing first search term])+1)))
```